# react native for tvOS

Tags: react-native, tvos, apple-tv, react-native-ios

I'm currently investigating the different opportunities for building a tvOS application, and see that the tvOS branch for react native by douglowder has been merged into the master branch.

Does anyone know if a tvOS application build with react native will be accepted into the App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else wondering about this it shouldn't be a problem.

> @apgl shouldn't be a problem. I have a React Native TV app in the App Store.
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2618#issuecomment-286449660